# Android using RXJava, How can I take an Observable with a list of integers and turn it into a list of ojects

Tags: android, rx-java

So this is what I have so far...

```
    public Observable<List<Integer>> getIds() {

        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super List<Integer>> subscriber) {
                try {
                    subscriber.onNext(mSource.getIds());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    subscriber.onError(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

This works fine and gets me the list of ids for the objects I'm trying to create

Then I need a function that returns a subscription to an Observer with a list of objects. I need to make a separate api call to getObject(int id) to get each of these objects.

```
    public Subscription getObjectList(Observer<List<Object>> observer) {
        return  mService.getIds()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

            // here is where i get lost...
            .map(new Func1<Observable<Integer>, Observable<List>>)
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What type is your `Observable` returned by `mService.getRoomIds()`?  Is that suppose to be the same `getIds` method that you've demonstrate above or is that a separate method completely?

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that when putting the code in. I edited it to fix that. mService.getIds() calls the getIds() function I put there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so since your `getIds()` method returns an `Observable<List<Integer>>` the proper way to create your `Func1` in `map` would be

```
.map(new Func1<List<Integer>, List<Object>>() {
```

It takes in a list of integers and will emit a list of objects.  I believe that is what you're trying to achieve.  Your final code could look something like so

```
public Subscription getObjectList(Observer<List<Object>> observer) {
    return getIds()
            .map(new Func1<List<Integer>, List<Object>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Object> call(List<Integer> integers) {
                    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
                    for (Integer id : integers) {
                        // Here's where you map each ids to an object and add it to the list
                        objects.add(getObject(id));
                    }
                    return objects;
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(observer);
}

// Add your own code here to load the object based on the id.
private Object getObject(Integer id) {
    return id;
}

// Replace with your own getIds from above
public Observable<List<Integer>> getIds() {
    return Observable.from(1, 2, 3).toList();
}
```

This should help you get started, let me know if there's something which you don't understand.

Comment: This is pretty close to what I have and I changed my code to match your and it works... but it's locking up the UI and loads the objects very slowly. If I'm getting the objects over a network 1 at a time it could take a bit of time. How can I get the List of ids and then in the background call getObject(id) and return with the list of objects to the main thread when everything is done?

Comment: @AndyFox that was my bad.  I took your code directly and forgot to move the `observeOn` after the `map`.  Because `observeOn` is posting the observable on the main thread the `map` function was being executed on the UI thread hence the UI was blocking.  I've updated the code to reflex this.  Try that out and let me know.